# Problem with generating images from unicode strings using imagemagick

Tags: unicode, imagemagick

i'm generating text images with following command sequence

```
convert -background "rgb(233, 231, 218)" -fill black \ 
-font media/fonts/FuturaStd-Medium.otf \
-pointsize 13 label:"ğüşıöçĞÜŞİÖÇ" -size 88x18 \
media/images/category_images/food-drink/category-top-row/tr_food-drink.png
```

which generates the following image.
[alt text http://img54.imageshack.us/img54/5461/trfooddrinkai3.png](http://img54.imageshack.us/img54/5461/trfooddrinkai3.png)

ğşĞİŞ are problematic, where others display correctly. my locale is en_US.UTF-8.
i'm also not having any problems trying the following example pinched from  http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#unicode

```
convert -background lightblue -fill blue -pointsize 32 \
      label:' é è à ù ç Ö ÿ ‘ ’ “ ” ° ² ³ € x ÷ '    label_i8n.gif
```

unicode characters displayed correctly in the label_i8n.gif.

how can i make imagemagick correctly convert these characters to image?

edit: following image is created with gimp using the same font. [alt text http://img93.imageshack.us/img93/1986/gimpfuturastdnc4.png](http://img93.imageshack.us/img93/1986/gimpfuturastdnc4.png)

Comment: Can you insert those characters in a text editor using that particular font? It could simply be missing those glyphs.

Comment: http://img93.imageshack.us/img93/1986/gimpfuturastdnc4.png created with gimp usingthe same font, displays characters correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the font doesn't have those glyphs, and that's why they are displayed as "?". Check it with the Character Map application.